# C++ Not Finding Installed Library

Tags: c++, gcc, libraries

I am desperately trying to install WebKitGTK+, but I have hit a two-hour impasse.

For one, the tarball provided on the website does not seem to follow any of the typical "build from source" conventions, and there are no instructions anywhere. Any build-from-source instructions they provide involve the unstable repository version, which I do not want to use...and anyhow, those do not seem to work.

I can find both the Webkit (libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev) and Webkit2 (libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev) versions on the repository (I love Synaptic Package Manager), but though I've installed them, C++ (CodeBlocks) fails on...

```
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
```

It is worth noting that one of my employees installed the same package (libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev) successfully from the Debian Wheezy repositories, and he can use them in his code just fine, with the same import statement.

I added the path to /usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0/webkit under Global Compiler Settings --> Search Directories --> Compiler. My employee and I both have the exact same paths to this library added - his work, mine don't.

I'm losing my mind now. Help?

Comment: Take a look on the compilation line of each cpp file. If you added the include directory properly you can find the `-I/usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0/webkit` in it. if it missing you haven't done it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeblocks go to the Project Build Options settings.  You can get there by right clicking on the project in the "Projects Management" panel on the left side of the screen and choosing 'Build Options' then clicking on the project itself(NOT just the debug/release options) in the window that shows up.  Click the "Search Directories" tab and in the compiler subtab you will need to enter the following path:

```
/usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0/
```

When adding them make sure you DO NOT add it as a relative path. Additionally in the "Compiler Settings" -> "Other Options" tab you might need to add one or more of:

```
`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 `
`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 `
`pkg-config --cflags pango `
`pkg-config --cflags cairo `
`pkg-config --cflags gdk-pixbuf-2.0 `
`pkg-config --cflags atk `
`pkg-config --cflags libsoup-2.4 `
```

On my system I could not get pkg-config to work for webkitgtk itself.